# Why is my YouTube subscribe button dimmed out and un-clickable?

Tags: youtube

Here is a screenshot of the actual YouTube button creator:

[image]

You can see the button is even dimmed there. It’s also dimmed when I embed on my site. Suggestions?

Comment: That could be because you are already subscribed. Try opening the web page on Incognito mode to see if its the same.

Comment: Of course it is. :/ Wanna add that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is because you are already subscribed to the channel.

Try opening the web page on Incognito mode to see if its the same.